# Standalone error after moving from Overleaf v2 to v1

Tags: standalone, overleaf

I've moved a project from Overleaf v2 to v1 by downloading all files and reuploading them to a blank v1 project. This has worked fine but I've now started getting the following error about 80% of the time I try to compile:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.sty:543:
Extra },
 or forgotten \endgroup.
l.543   }
         %
```

I haven't touch any of the standalone sections of my project (tikz figures in separate files)

I've tried recompiling from scratch but am still getting the error 80% of the time.

Thanks

Comment: _(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)_ Overleaf v2 uses TL207, while v1 uses TL2016, so this may be due to different versions of packages. You can also contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, so that the team can have a closer look.

Comment: ...and of course I meant "v2 uses TL2017", sorry for the typo.